# Divisibility criterion for 11

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What is a quick way to prove **using induction** the following fact:
"A number is a multiple of 11 if and only if the sum of its even-placed digits minus the sum of its odd-placed digits is also a multiple of 11"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The quickest way to help you is that you show us what you have tried.

Comment: You are right. See my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use congruences. $10\equiv -1\mod11$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This was also my argument. I proved by induction that it holds $10^n\equiv (-1)^n \mod 11$, and then the result readily follows by writing a number in its decimal representation. But I was wondering if there exists another "more direct" way.